# Prolog member predicate possibilities rule

Tags: list, prolog, member

A premium pizza is comprised of exactly 40 ounces of toppings. There can be multiple entries of each topping, as long as the total weight is equal to 40 ounces.

```
Pepperoni           4 
Sausage             10
Bacon               6
Onion               5
Mushroom            7
```

For example, a pizza can contain 1 topping of pepperoni, 2 toppings of sausage, 1 topping
of bacon, and 2 toppings of onion : `1*4 + 2*10 + 1*6 + 2*5 = 40` (ounces)

A pizza cannot contain 7 toppings of bacon : `7 * 6 = 42 > 40A` pizza cannot contain only 3 toppings of sausage : `3*10 = 30 < 40`

Define a rule `pizza(P, S, B, O, M)` to find out how many of each topping can be contained
on a pizza, where `P, S, B, O, and M` are the weight (in ounces) of the Pepperoni, Sausage,
Bacon, Onion, and Mushroom toppings respectively.

```
pizza(P,S,B,O,M):-
member(P,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]),
member(S,[0,1,2,3,4]),
member(B,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),
member(O,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),
member(M,[0,1,2,3,4,5]),
S is 4*P + 10*S + 6*B + 5*O + 7*M,
S =:= 40.
```

I have defined the following rule but it returns false instead of the possible combination of toppings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using`S` for both the sausage weight and the weight of the whole pizza.